# How to fetch the result inside a stored procedure or a trigger?

Tags: mysql, fetch, procedure

How to fetch the result inside a stored procedure or a trigger?

Here is my code :

```
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS `log_activity`;

DELIMITER ;;

CREATE TRIGGER `log_activity` AFTER INSERT ON tbl_1
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN

    SET @RESULT = (SELECT id,name FROM tbl2);

END ;;
```

i want my code something like :

WHILE @RESULT
BEGIN

```
//i want to get the value of the id and name
```

END;

Comment: `PROCEDURE`  can return value not `TRIGGER`

Comment: What is your exact requirement?

Comment: How cna i do that in procedure then?

Answer (score 0):

Read this:
http://www.roseindia.net/sql/trigger/mysql-trigger-after-insert.shtml
and may be this for future reference:
http://www.roseindia.net/sql/trigger/mysql-trigger-after-update.shtml

Pay attention to "new" and "old" prefixes before the field names